# condition statements involving coordinates

Tags: coordinates, conditional-statements

I need help with making an if/then statement which depends on a movie clip being between a certain set of coordinates for the rule to work. Here is the code I tried to use:

if (honey1.x >=165 <=231.x;
    honey1.y >=295 <=330.y;) {
    honeyOne = true}
    }

I haven't had much luck finding a lot of help on condition statements beyond very simple or unrelated notes. If anyone knows how to make a statement like this work, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

A method to test that a number is between two bounds might look like this.

```
bool IsBetweenInclusive(int value, int lower, int upper)
{
    return value >= lower 
        && value <= upper;
}
```

That's easily extendable to a point structure

```
bool IsBetweenInclusive(Point value, Point lower, Point upper)
{
    return IsBetweenInclusive(value.X, lower.X, upper.X)
        && IsBetweenInclusive(value.Y, lower.Y, upper.Y);
}
```

If your coordinate system is in a double or float kind of number space, you'll need to do work to account for rounding.